# Xilinx ISE implementation stage issues

Tags: fpga, xilinx, spartan-6

For the placement errors, someone told me that **I cannot use two serdes in an IOB in 1:8 mode because the IOB has two iserdes for two IO's. if a 1:8 serdes takes 2 serdes, then two 1:8 would take 4. the IOB does not have 4.**

However, if look inside the [placement error log](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XwBbKSmTq3/), it seems that only [OSERDES](https://github.com/promach/DDR/blob/main/ddr3_memory_controller.v#L751-L762) has issue, but not ISERDES . Why ?

Besides, I did not modify SERDES_RATIO of the [demo verilog example](https://secure.xilinx.com/webreg/clickthrough.do?cid=140956) that comes with [XAPP1064 appnote](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp1064.pdf#page=17). SERDES_RATIO defaults to 8 in the original demo example. So, I wonder why SERDES_RATIO=8 would not work during placement.

Could anyone advise about this ?

I roughly understand what the placement error messages are trying to convey. When I use IOSERDES2 primitives, the tool expects the IOSERDES2 primitives to be at the edge of the FPGA chip.

However, for DDR3 memory RAM, I have an extra [IOBUF](https://github.com/promach/DDR/blob/main/ddr3_memory_controller.v#L906-L921) for inout-type dq signal. But the tool did not expect the existence of this IOBUF primitive though.

In other words, IOBUF has some conflicting placement location with IOSERDES2

Please comment about this.

### New edit updates

Someone pointed out to me that in https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp1064.pdf#page=20 , **When the SerDes factor is 5 to 8 or the phase detector function is selected, two ISERDES2s are required and the pin next to the active input (which must be a master or _p pin) is blocked from use as a synchronous input since the necessary logic is already occupied.**

I suppose this is the main root cause for the placement errors.

However, could I get around this issue without much verilog code modification ?

[image: log1]

[image: log2]

Comment: This is quite biased to the tool (old tool as well) rather than design. You might get better response bin Xilinx forum.

Comment: @MituRaj I have updated the question with some new edits which could be main root cause.